# How to select a random number to either 0 or 1 using javascript?

Tags: javascript

#### I want to select either 0 or 1 using math.random().

Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) );

Comment: You know what you want to do and have code that should be doing it. What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is almost correct, but you want

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
```

Comment: This could however potentially floor to 2 as `Math.random()` could output 0.99999999999. which * 2 would output as 2

Comment: `Math.floor(0.99999999999 * 2)` is 1 in my browser

Comment: how about Math.round(Math.random())

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) +0.5);
```